# HQL map with distinct not work

Tags: hql

I have a trouble using HQL (in Groovy):
A simple query works without problems, like below (please note that I am using distinct):

```
def eqLiquid = liq.Liquidacion.executeQuery(
"""SELECT 
        distinct b.id ,
        l.nombre as name
        FROM Liquidacion l JOIN l.detalles ll JOIN ll.bioquimico b
        WHERE l.id=:liqid
        """, [liqid: liqid])
```

But I need to return these data as a map, then I have modified the query (only add new map()) :

```
def eqLiquid = liq.Liquidacion.executeQuery(
"""SELECT new map(
        distinct b.id ,
        l.nombre as name
        )
        FROM Liquidacion l JOIN l.detalles ll JOIN ll.bioquimico b
        WHERE l.id=:liqid
        """, [liqid: liqid])
```

Then I get an error: "unexpected token: distinct near line 2, column 17 [SELECT new map(
        distinct b.id ,"

If I quit the distinct  in the last query, it works. 
Anyone had this problem? 
It seems that MAP and DISTINCT can not work togheter in an HQL query

Comment: maybe you just need to remove `distinct`? or you can build map on the level of groovy: `def map = liq.Liquidacion.rows( ... ).collectEntries{ row-> [row.id , row.name] }`

Comment: I can not remove distinct, because i need only the distinct ids.  I see your idea about to build the map with groovy, but I can not get it working yet....